# What's the meaning of this benefit in my contract?

Tags: salary, working-abroad, job-offer

I'm new to this site. I'm not sure it's the right place to ask my question, at least there is a 'salary tag' here.

I am invited to work abroad in a restaurant as a Sushi chef for two years. There's a list of benefits that I will get if I work there. Here's some of the list:

- Every two years - One month salary (total $1400)
- Every two years - Two months vacation
- Every two years - One round-trip ticket home

My question are:

1. What's the meaning of point one? Am I paid $1400 for two years? That would mean $58 a month???
2. What's the meaning of point two? Do I get a vacation / day off for two months (60 days) for two years working?
3. In point three, do I only get one ticket for two years?
4. Are these benefits normal? Should I sign the contract?

Comment: I think this is better suited for the Workplace SE.

Comment: Oh.. ok. I'll remove it and create one there. Thx

Comment: I think the first item is a _bonus_ - you'd get that in _addition_ to your normal salary.

Comment: What is your home country, and what country would you be working in?

Answer (score 3):

**First question.** Normally one has 2 weeks vacation per year. One month every 2 years is then normal. But they give you 2 months vacation, one will be paid, the other no. As if you would be paid 700$ a month on vacation.

**Second question.** So you will have one year with no vacation, the other year with a long vacation. Every 2 years you will have 2 months off, one of which will be paid 1400$. Why not vacation every year? It is not logical.

**Third question.** Yes only one ticket every two years. This is normal. If you have family, some companies will pay for your children. It is negociable. You have to add your 1400$ of vacation pay to the price of the round trip. If a round trip is 3000$ the employer will then have to pay you 4400$ for these two months vacations.  **Last question.** Normal, but everything is negociable and up to you.

**Should you sign?** Investigate first who is your employer. A company or a lone guy who could go bankrupt and leave you in the cold. **Is your employer a financially sound company?** 
What about the **working permit**? What will he do to legalize your situation? You also have to know about **tax issues**. What is the amount after taxes? What about your income tax in that country and yours? Who will help you with the tax forms? There are a lot of questions that need to be answered before signing. **Where will you live?** Alone or in a dormitory? **If you are sick? Any insurance ?**

May **I suggest checking** [this website for international jobs in culinary arts](https://jobs.goabroad.com/search/culinary-arts-cooking/jobs-abroad-1). It could help you decide before signing a contract. Once you are in another country, there are a lot of things that can go wrong and you need to be sure your employer will be there to help. I had bad experiences and good experiences, so investigate very well before signing.